# Contradiction in equal vector spaces proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm studying the module Algebra, and was reading the course book "Álgebra. Aplicaciones a Teoría de Códigos". I got stuck on this problem because of a contradiction.

**Question:** In $\mathbb{R}_3$, we consider the base $B=[(1,0,1),(2,1,-1),(1,1,0)] \subseteq  \mathbb{R}_3$ and the subspaces $T$ and $S$, such that:

$T\equiv\begin{Bmatrix}
x= & \lambda +4\mu  \\
y= & \lambda +2\mu  \\
z= & 0 
\end{Bmatrix}$

$S=\mathcal{L}((1,0,0)_B, (0,0,1)_B)$

Demonstrate that $S=T$.

**Answer:**

$S=\mathcal{L}((1,0,0)_B, (0,0,1)_B) \equiv S=\mathcal{L}((3,1,0), (1,1,0)).$

This means that:

$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda \\
\mu
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{pmatrix}
$

Therefore:

$S\equiv\begin{Bmatrix}
x= & 3\lambda +\mu  \\
y= & \lambda +\mu  \\
z= & 0 
\end{Bmatrix}$

However for $\lambda = 1, \mu = 1$:

$S=\begin{Bmatrix}
x= 4  \\
y= 2  \\
z= 0 
\end{Bmatrix}$

$T=\begin{Bmatrix}
x= 5  \\
y= 3  \\
z= 0 
\end{Bmatrix}$

This is a contradiction, as $S \neq T$.

***Notes answer*:** As $dim(S)=dim(T)\wedge S\subseteq T \Rightarrow S=T$. (I found such information in my notes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no contradiction. You proved that$$\mathcal L\left(\{(3,1,0),(1,1,0)\}\right)=\left\{3\lambda+\mu,\lambda+\mu,0\mid\lambda,\mu\in\Bbb R\right\}.\label{a}\tag1$$You have no reason to assume that the RHS of \eqref{a} is different from$$\left\{\lambda+4\mu,\lambda+2\mu,0\mid\lambda,\mu\in\Bbb R\right\}.\label{b}\tag2$$And, in fact, they are equal. Note that\begin{align}\mathcal L\left(\{(3,1,0),(1,1,0)\}\right)&=\mathcal L\left(\{(3,1,0)+(1,1,0),(1,1,0)\}\right)\\&=\mathcal L\left(\{(4,2,0),(1,1,0)\}\right)\\&=\mathcal L\left(\{(1,1,0),(4,2,0)\}\right).\end{align}And now, by the the same type of computations that you have already done, you can see that $\mathcal L\left(\{(1,1,0),(4,2,0)\}\right)$ is equal to \eqref{b}.